# How to not lose fullscreen when focus on a plugin in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, fullscreen, greasemonkey

I set fullscreen with `mozRequestFullScreen` and when click on a plugin (Unity Web Player in this example), exit fullscreen and console says: "Has been abandoned fullscreen because a plugin window has received focus."

And in Chrome I can click on the same plugin and don't lose fullscreen that I set with `webkitRequestFullScreen`...

Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and by reviewing the firefox/gecko source I realised this 'logic' (in quotes out of spite) was being invoked when an element in the DOM was being modified.

Therefore I solved this issue by removing the code which modified the DOM and replacing it with a CSS only solution.

I can't be more specific about how you could solve it in your particular case without knowing more about your code.